# как выполнить bash скрипт из python3 и сохранить результат в файл

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, bash, shell, subprocess

Нужно выполнить bush скрипт из python3 как сторонний процесс и сохранить результат в файл (успешный он или ошибочный). Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
run_subprocess = subprocess.Popen(
['bash ' + '/home/user/script'],
cwd = '/home/user/case',
shell = True,
stdout='/home/user/out',
stderr='/home/user/err')
```

После запуска выходит ошибка:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Что не так? Есть ли альтернативный способ решить данную задачу?

Comment: Вам нужно сохранить весь вывод команды? Или достаточно узнать код завершения?

Comment: Нужно сохранить весь вывод, чтобы потом отобразить его в pyqt5 виджете

Comment: Переписать скрипт на python не помогает?

Comment: Все получилось через run(), и сохранение в файл оказалось лишним:                                                output = subprocess.run(["bash", "script_path"],
cwd = "case_path", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как всё легко настраивается через простой `os.system()`. Попробуй это:

```
import os
os.system("bash test.sh > output 2> errors &")
```

Comment: Сначала нужно перейти в указанную директорию, потом там выполнить скрипт. И нужен именно subprocess

Comment: Ну так просто правь строку - `os.system("bash " + dir + script + " > " output...`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через subprocess.check_output. Получаешь результат в переменной, а потом записываешь в файл.

> subprocess.check_output(args, *, input=None, stdin=None, stderr=None,
>   shell=False, universal_newlines=False, timeout=None) - выполняет
>   команду и возвращает её вывод.

[Источник](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-subprocess.html)